# Allocated memory keeps increasing

Tags: android

Allocated memory keeps increasing, didn't decreased for a 1mb...
Looks like garbage collector has not been called at all.

I have main activity with tab layout and 4 fragments (like on instagram) and with a lot of bitmaps which I get from the server.
Once I download data from internet, I use to save ArrayList of objects to be called if that fragment been called again.
Example:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (itemsArray != null) {
        savedListState = new Bundle();
        savedListState.putSerializable("myKey", itemsArray);
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (savedListState != null) {
        customGridProfileAdapter = new CustomGridProfileAdapter(getActivity(), itemsArray);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridProfileAdapter);
        savedListState = null;
    }
}
```

I'm not destroying views at all.
I thought that was the problem, but looks like it's not, because when I switch between activities it still works the same way, even when I destroy views of activity that's being replaced.
So what to do? Why garbage collector don't decrease allocated memory?
And what should I do about holding already downloaded items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a memory leak in your app. To learn more about memory leaks [watch this wonderful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mU1VcKx8Wzw). From my experience, every app that is large and uses other api's will suffer from this issue.